# onclick function not working at first click

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, onclick

i tried to set up a onclick function on a "reset" button type, which will only work if i click it twice, i've even tried it as a normal button type with the same results. I've placed it on other parts of the site but the same results persists.

The functions it does is that it erases out text that appears dynamically everytime you add a new order. And the html reset functions wipes out the rest of the sites input, which is ok i guess.

Here you can visit the website and see for yourself:

http://www.premiere-produkter.no/pp/lagersalg/index.php

Here is a part of the code,

```
var tester;
var tester = function () {
    document.form['reset'].onclick = function () {
        contact_box_kurv.innerHTML = ("").replace (/,/g, ''); 
        return false;
    };
};
</script>

<h2><INPUT TYPE="RESET" name="reset" id="reset" VALUE="Tøm Handlekurv" onclick="tester()"></h2>
```

Note: To see the function work on the website you will need to add an order.

Comment: Simply because you are using onclick twice..

Comment: Removing commas from an empty string?

Comment: @Musa - Better safe than, sorry. You, never know, where commas, are going to spring, up. ,,,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your button has an inline `onclick` attribute that calls `tester()`. So on first click it'll do whatever `tester()` does - which is replace that with another `onclick` set to the anonymous function inside `tester()`. So then on second click it'll do what that second anonymous function does.

Try this instead:

```
var tester = function () {
    contact_box_kurv.innerHTML = ("").replace (/,/g, ''); 
    return false;
};
```

(I.e., have the desired functionality directly in `tester()`.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to put this script separately:

```
window.onload = function ()
{
    document.form['reset'].onclick = function () {
    contact_box_kurv.innerHTML = ("").replace (/,/g, ''); 
    return false;
    };
};
```

Remove the event handler script.

Comment: Did not work as well as nnnn's answer but thanks for the help anyways :)